# Zero diagonal operators and Riesz bases

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, schauder-basis

- We shall concern ourselves only with separable complex Hilbert spaces and bounded linear operators on them. An operator $A: \mathcal H\to \mathcal H$ is said to be a zero diagonal operator if $(Ae_n, e_n) = 0$ for some orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$.
- A base $\{b_n\}$ is called a Riesz base if there is an invertible operator $T$, and an orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$ such that $Te_n = b_n$ for all $n\ge 1$. Given a base $\mathcal B = \{b_n\}$ of $\mathcal H$, we can associate every operator $A: \mathcal H\to \mathcal H$ with a matrix $[A]_{\mathcal B}$ in a canonical way. Furthermore, we denote the base biorthogonal to $\mathcal B$ by $\mathcal B^* = \{b_n^*\}$, i.e., $(b_i, b_j^*) = \delta_{ij}$ for all $i,j\ge 1$. Then, the diagonal of $[A]_{\mathcal B}$ is $\{(Ab_n, b_n^*): n\ge 1\}$.

The first page of [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20489272) says:

> Thus, for an operator $A$, being similar to a zero diagonal operator can be described as having zeros everywhere in the diagonal of $[A]_{\mathcal B}$ (i.e., $(Ab_n, b_n^*) = 0$ for some Riesz base $\{b_n\}$).

In view of the statement above, I am trying to show that an operator $A$ is similar to a zero diagonal operator if and only if there exists a Riesz base $\{b_n\}$ such that $(Ab_n, b_n^*) = 0$ for all $n\ge 1$. I'd appreciate any help with the same.

1. Suppose $A$ is similar to a zero diagonal operator, i.e., $(S^{-1}AS e_n, e_n) = 0$ for some orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$ and an invertible operator $S$. I must find a Riesz base $\{b_n\}$, and I tried to see if $\{Se_n\}$ or $\{S^{-1} e_n\}$ might work (they don't).
2. Suppose there exists a Riesz base $\{b_n\}$ such that $(Ab_n, b_n^*) = 0$ for all $n\ge 1$. There is an invertible operator $T$ and an orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$ such that $Te_n = b_n$. So, $(ATe_n, b_n^*) = 0$ for all $n\ge 1$.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both statements follow from the following facts:

$1.)$ Any $S: \mathcal{H}\to \mathcal{H}$ has an adjoint operator $S^*$ $\bigg($i.e $(Sx,y) = (x,S^*y)$ for all $x,y \in \mathcal{H} \bigg)$
$2.)$ If $\{e_n\}$ is an orthonormal basis, then the dual Riesz Basis of $Se_n$ is $(S^{-1})^*e_n$.

From here, all you need to see is that:
\begin{align}
(S^{-1}AS e_n , e_n) & = (ASe_n, (S^{-1})^*e_n) \\
& = (Ab_n, b_n^*)
\end{align}

The first fact is standard in intro Hilbert space theory.
The second fact is not too difficult to prove:

Suppose $e_n$ is an orthonormal basis and $S$ an operator. Then any $f \in \mathcal{H}$ can be expresses as

$$f = \sum_{n} (f,e_n)e_n $$ and this implies

\begin{align}
f = SS^{-1}(f) & = \sum_n (S^{-1}f,e_n)e_n \\
& = \sum_n(f,(S^{-1})^*e_n )S(e_n)
\end{align}

Letting $f = S(e_m) = b_m$  and $(S^{-1})^*(e_n) = b_n^*$, we obtain

$$b_m = \sum_n (b_m, b_n^*)b_n $$

By linear independence of $\{b_n \}$ (which follows from $S$ being an invertible operator), we must have $(b_n,b_n^*) = \delta_{mn}$.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, is this choice of a biorthogonal basis *unique*?

Comment: Given any basis (Riesz or not), the dual basis is unique. (Assuming your first bullet point). Things get more interesting when you're working with things that are not bases (frames).

Comment: How does one prove uniqueness, though?